# OAuth call from Rest Client

Tags: rest, curl, oauth

As I am new to working on OAuth and from Curl script it's working fine . But trying to call from Advances Rest Client getting 500 internal server error ..

while trying to create a new client from Rest client as,

http://localhost:2021/oauth_uri?client_id=unique_client_id&client_secret=client_secret_value&scope[]=clients.admin&authorized_grant_types[]=password&authorized_grant_types[]=authorization_code&authorized_grant_types[]=refresh_token&authorized_grant_types[]=client_credentials&authorized_grant_types[]=implicit&access_token_validity=900&refresh_token_validity=2592000

,Content-Type: application/json and

Authorization: Bearer Access_Token value

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked what is the code that gets generated from REST Client. You can do that by exporting it. Also give a try to POSTMAN incase you still can'r figure out the issue.